# Symfony Console Google Cloud SQL Connecting

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine

I use Google Cloud to host my API which uses twitter real-time API.
In order to trigger the Twitter API, I need to establish a connection with it via command line.

I have used Symfony console to call the twitter realtime.
When I connect to the API on other routes the database connection works, but when I run the ./console command it can't establish the connection to the database.

I get

> 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused'

which doesn't explain much.I'm wondering if the reason for this is because the file from which the request goes is not from the public folder.

The connection class looks like this:

```
class PDOCompat extends PDO
{

    /**
     * COnnect to database
     *
     * @param $config
     * @return PDO|string
     */
    public function connect($config)
    {
        try{
            $connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['db_host'].';dbname='.$config['db_name'],$config['db_user'],$config['db_password']);
            //$connection = new PDO($config['db_socket'].';dbname='.$config['db_name'].';',$config['db_user'],$config['db_password']);
            $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            ** stuff
        }
        return $connection;
    }

}
```

I have really no ideas how to make it work since I don't know where to start.Everything that I had in mind I tried it out and it didn't work.

> Note: It's working on local(the real-time API) and the connection is working on both local and server when it connects over the route.

Comment: just a guess, try adding --env=prod to your command, if it works then you can see on config differences between the environments and fix it.

Comment: @SergeiKutanov its on compute engine

Comment: How exactly do you run the ./console command? What does it contain? Have you checked your database logs?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to be using a custom driver? You can use Doctrine's driver which works just fine. The other thing - do you have mysql running on the host? Is it listening to the mysql port `3306`? Have you checked your `iptables` to see if it allows connection to that port from the IP you are trying to connect?

Comment: You do not specify a port in your PDO connection construtor. So it takes the `mysql.default_port` from the php.ini. My guess: it's different (or not set) in your server's CLI php.ini... Can you try setting the $dsn (first parameter) to `'mysql:host='.$config['db_host'].';dbname='.$config['db_name'].';port='.$config['db_port']` (and of course define `db_port` in your config). btw, I agree with @tftd, you could/should use doctrine's driver.

Comment: @DaAmidza ping? I don't see how we're supposed to "guess" what's wrong when you're not providing any info. Furthermore, the bounty is now off, because nobody could even attempt to answer your question due to total lack of communication. -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The cloud SQL have by default closed connections from outside. You need to go to Authorization tab in cloud SQL instance detail and allow connection from Compute engine instance IP address.

You can read more info here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-access-control

Comment: If you have red the question you could see a paragraph where I have said that it works when I connect to the database when I'm accessing it over HTTP. So when I'm accessing it over a ./comand file it's not working.